# Using a Widget in Activity

Tags: android

it's me again :-)

Is there a way to use a widget (for home screen) in my own activites?
i think the homescreen is made with java, too?!

i do not want to change thinks in the widget, i still want to display them.

Regards
FLy

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to "re-use" a widget's layout and may be its base code, that is possible. I don't think it will be a good idea [or possible] to display a widget as an activity.

There are a lot of limitations in the number of view elements that can be used inside a widget. And again the way you will update a widget [RemoteViews] is actually very different from that of an Activity.

So in short, the answer would be a "NO".

Edit: This question has also been asked and answered a lot of times: [difference between view and widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168549/difference-between-view-and-widget)