# Android: Is there a real difference between a widget and a view?

Tags: android, view, widget

Is there a real difference (other than terminology) between a widget and a view? Which is the one I can put into my app just like a standard SeekBar or a Button?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899928/what-is-the-difference-between-views-and-widgets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A View is an object that you can put on your layout such as a TextView, EditText, ListView, or ImageView.  It is the basic building block for user interface components.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

A widget is a group of ViewGroups and Views that you can put on the users home screen or in another application.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: Thanks Z. So say I want to make a volume knob that I can rotate (think circular SeekBar), and I want to put it in my app, which is a simulator for an audio panel, would I use a View or a Widget?

Comment: You would want to make that a View.

Comment: You could extend the View or ImageView class and make your own custom KnobView.

Comment: If I've already created the knob itself and it functions well, but it's in its own Eclipse project, would I be able to insert that into my overall app as a View? Do you know of a good tutorial that can teach me how to do that?

Comment: You could export it as a .jar. The problem with .jar files is it can't contain the xml files needed for the layout.  Another option would be to turn your separate project into an Android library.  A third option would be to just copy and paste the files in between projects which I find easiest.  Also take a look at http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html.

Comment: The library option worked like a charm! The hard part was linking my app to the library project's methods but I figured it out eventually. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ListView is in the widget package. So not a View as you said... I know. confusing. I still do not know what the rule is :D